# Building a grid of circles with text inside and... moving things around

Tags: javascript, raphael

I'm desperately trying to build a grid with circles and text inside. So far so good, I can do that... My real problem is being able to find each set and move it around (text AND circle). I've tried to look at similar issues, but I can't find out by myself... If someone could give me a clue, I'd greatly appreciate.

Here's a simplified code (only 1 line) that doesn't work :

```
$(function() {
        // Prepare drawing zone
        var paper = Raphael(document.getElementById('question'), '100%', '100%');

        var word = 'Sunday';

        var group = new Array();
        // Draw 5 circles with text inside
        for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
            group[i] = paper.set();
            group[i].push(paper.circle(50+i*60, 50, 30));
            group[i].push(paper.text(50+i*60, 50, word));

            group[i].click(function() {
                group[i].translate(20,20); // HERE'S THE PROBLEM group[i] DOESN'T WORK !
                group[i].rotate(Math.random() * 90);
            });
             }
    });
```

I can't find out a way of 'calling' my sets for further reference...
Of course, If I have only 1 set (and no array=, it works...

Thanks for your help!

Celfred.

Edit : jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rrWqM/

Edit : I'm not sure I'm clear enough. What I would like is to be able to click on 1 circle (and text), and see THIS circle AND text move. If I click on another one, then the other one moves... It sounds so simple I can't believe I'm stuck on that... Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [fiddle][http://jsfiddle.net/DusKv/1/]

The problem in your code is that the i variable does not have the right value when the click callback function is invoked. You can work around this by defining a local variable in the enclosing scope.

```
// Prepare drawing zone
var paper = Raphael(document.getElementById('question'), '100%', '100%');

var word = 'Sunday';

var group = new Array();
// Draw 10 circles with text inside
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var set = paper.set();
    set.push(paper.circle(50 + i * 30, 50, 50));
    set.push(paper.text(50 + i * 30, 50, word));

    set.click(function() {
        set.translate(Math.random() * 350, Math.random() * 380); // HERE'S THE PROBLEM group[i] DOESN'T WORK !
        set.rotate(Math.random() * 90);
    });
    group[i] = set;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but... this doesn't seem to work either :-(  The only circle moving is the last one, even if I click on the first circle...

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I found a turnaround this way : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frn5k/)

Now I get a correct reference in my click event.

I must admit I didn't quite understand my initial problem. If you could at least tell me if this new 'solution' sounds good to you, I'd appreciate ;-)

Celfred.